# Error relacionado con sql_mode=only_full_group_by al ejecutar consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un ORDER BY, tengo una consulta la cual me muestra unos productos y la consulta me funciona al momento en que se ejecuta mi sistema, pero le agregué un ORDER BY y la consulta me muestra el siguiente  error, eh buscado en internet, pero no me queda del todo claro el porqué la consulta no funciona unicamente agregandole el ORDER BY, les muestro el error y la consulta

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'hol_products.Productos.Nombre'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

y esta es la consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(Nombre) Total, Nombre, Registro, Presentacion, ViaAdministracion, imagen, GROUP_CONCAT(Imag ORDER BY Imag desc) imag, GROUP_CONCAT(idProductos) idProductos 
FROM Productos 
INNER JOIN ProductoEspecie ON Productos.idProductos= ProductoEspecie.idProducto 
INNER JOIN especie on especie.idEspecie= ProductoEspecie.idEspecie 
INNER JOIN tipoProducto on Productos.idTipoProducto= tipoProducto.idTipo 
WHERE Productos.nombre LIKE '%lassy%' ORDER BY OrdenProductos ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto pasa cuando mezclas funciones agregadas con campos simples y no incluyes todos los campos simple en el GROUP BY de tu query.  Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones:

1. Agregar la clausula GROUP BY y añadir todos los campos simples a esa clausula.
2. Desactivar la variable only_full_group_by así:

   ```
   SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
   ```

Comment: Funciona perfecto

Comment: Para hacer el cambio persistente, se puede modificar la propiedad `sqlmode` en el archivo `my.cnf`/`my.ini`, por ejemplo: `sqlmode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`